# Using AdWords Scripts, how can I replace a feed in Merchant Center with a .txt file from Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

When IT does an update on our website, we have to shut down shopping ads or our traffic will be down for a few days due to Google errors. To do this we usually have someone manually upload a new .txt feed file to Merchant Center with all products listed as 'Out of Stock,' then when the site is back we reupload a .txt feed file with the products restored.

The problem is we can do this with the 'Rules' tool in Merchant Center to set all products to 'Out of Stock,' but we can't use the same rule to set all to 'In Stock' because some items actually are out of stock.

In scripts, its simple enough to connect to Merchant Center and a feed, now I'm just hung up on how to get a .txt file from Google Drive to Merchant Center.

```
function PullPauseFeed(){
  var filesIterator = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Google_Mex_Feed_2016-10-21_OUT OF STOCK.txt');
          while (filesIterator.hasNext()) {
            var file = filesIterator.next().getAs('text/plain');
          } 
         return file;
}

function MexPause() {
  var merchantId = '1111';
  var datafeedId = '1111';
  var newFeed = PullPauseFeed();

  ShoppingContent.Datafeeds.update(newFeed, merchantId, datafeedId);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [external data integration](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/features/external-data).

This is an AdWords Scripts feature which allows you to integrate with external data sources, for example Google Spreadsheets in Google Drive. AdWords scripts allows you to read data from and write data to spreadsheets through the [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) interface.

In your case wherein you use `.txt` file from Google Drive, you have an option to  further leverage Google Drive with the [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) interface. This allows scripts to create, find, and modify arbitrary files on Google Drive.

Please try going through the given documentations and see available methods or properties that you can use.

Comment: Hi Teyam, thank you for the reply.  

I've worked a lot with Sheets and Drive to manipulate data and save targets to use for bidding adjustments in Scripts, I'm just hung up on how to replace the .txt file in our feed.  

When I pull a .txt file from our Drive as plain text, I can log the data.  I just can't quite figure out the step to load it into Merchant Center as a .txt.  I'm trying to piece together what the 'resources' variable can entail exactly in the Datafeeds.update function. 

I don't need the data in the .txt file, I just need to transfer the intact file to Merchant Center.